# Which bst file is easier to edit and how?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I am currently using a `.bst` file of a university for my bibliography, which I am mostly happy with. However, it can't deal with two references in the same `\citep{}` command that have the same first author and year. It says that there is no distinguishable letter and results in just a question mark for one of the references (even though these references work fine individually):

> ...this is to test the references (Lastname1 et al., 2005,?)
>
> Lastname1, Lastname2, and Lastname3 (2005). Title. Journal, 1, 1.
>
> Lastname1, Lastname2, Lastname3, and Lastname4 (2005). Title.
>   Journal, 1, 1.

I would like this to be dealt with the way `apalike.bst` handles this:

> ...this is to test the references (Lastname1 et al., 2005a,b)
>
> Lastname1, Lastname2, and Lastname3 (2005a). Title. Journal, 1:1.
>
> Lastname1, Lastname2, Lastname3, and Lastname4 (2005b). Title. Journal,
>   1:1.

However, I have no idea how to edit the `.bst` file to do this. I'm not sure whether it would be easier to edit `apalike.bst` to look like the `uni` file. But this would involve changing quite a lot of smaller things I think.

I'm not sure how to properly do a MWE for this, but:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}    
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

this is to test the references
\citep{lastnamea,lastnameb}

\cleardoublepage
%\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliographystyle{uni_style_file} 
\bibliography{journals}

\end{document}
```

and `journals.bib`:

```
@Article{lastnamea,
  Title                    = {Title},
  Author                   = {Lastname1 and Lastname2 and Lastname3},
  Journal                  = {Journal},
  Year                     = {2005},
  Pages                    = {1},
  Volume                   = {1}
}



@Article{lastnameb,
  Title                    = {Title},
  Author                   = {Lastname1 and Lastname2 and Lastname3 and 
Lastname4},
  Journal                  = {Journal},
  Year                     = {2005},
  Pages                    = {1},
  Volume                   = {1}
}
```

I can provide the uni style file if needed, but am not sure how.

Comment: It sounds like `uni_style_file.bst` was designed to take into account only the first three authors' surnames when constructing the year label. (Why? Why ask why??) If that's the case, it's going to be almost hopeless to edit the bst file and try to re-enable a more rational method. At this stage, you should probably look into using the `makebst` utility (part of the [custom-bib](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package) to create a new, suitable bst file from scratch. The utility is entirely menu-driven, with sensible default choices.

Comment: Incidentally, the honest answer to your question, "Which bst file is easier to edit?", has to be "editing bst files is never easy" -- unless you happen to be an expert in the rather uncommon stack-based programming idiom that's employed by BibTeX. That's an important reason for why I recommeded, in my earlier comment, looking into running the `makebst` utility to create a brand-new bst file from scratch. A side benefit of creating a new bst file is that it'll be fully compatible with the `natbib` citation management package (since the utility was written by the author of the `natbib` package).

Comment: i dont think it is to do with how many author's surnames are there (i cant check until tomorrow now) - so much as that it cant account for any doubles of the way the reference is presented in the text (e.g. it cant cope with brown et al 2005 and brown et al 2005 both resulting from \citep - regardless of how many authors the et al represents). i suspect this would also happen with brown and smith 2005  and brown and smith 2005 - if both were different papers in the same \citep. i guess this is pretty close to what you said in your first comment though...

Comment: how hard is it to use the makebst utility? i am getting pretty tight on time - and wondering if i should make do with apalike...

Comment: See this https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography

Comment: @BaiSmi - Speaking for myself, I think the makebst utility is pretty straightforward to use. Do be prepared to answer lots of detailed questions. (In all all likelihood, you'll be safe choosign the default answer to most questions.) Since I have no idea what your university's bib style does or achieves, I can't offer more specific advice. If you think that "making do with apalike" is acceptable, do consider that option as well...

Comment: Ok, thank you. The university doesn't have strict reference guidelines, so long as the choice is appropriate for the field you study. The bst file is not official, it was designed by the computer sciences dept. I just like the look of it. I will have a look at makebst, but apalike should hopefully be fine if I have any problems. (sorry "making do" was a bit too negative)